# How do I use kwargs to create a master function?

Tags: python, function, arguments, keyword-argument

I have three functions created and they are the following:

```
StoreInfo(D1)
GetResidual(D1)
FindAlternative(D1)
```

They all take the same input of "D1".

There are instances where I do not want to use all three of them, so I am attempting to create a master function called "Master()" whose parameters determine which of the three functions I wish to use. I want it to be like the following:

```
Master(StoreInfo,GetAlternative)
```

And the function should run both the StoreInfo() and GetAlternative() function.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You could just call the passed functions:

```py
def master(*functions):
    for function in functions:
        function(D1)
```

Comment: maybe a wrapper for a dynamic `D1`?

Comment: @cards dynamic in what sense?

Comment: make _master_ a decorator to let the freedom of the choice of the  parameter

Comment: @cards based on what OP seems to have requested, I don't see how `master` could be a decorator... it's supposed to call the functions that are passed to it, if you decorate one function then it passes just that one there... like, I don't get how and what you want it to decorate

Comment: Sorry, I will post a solution with what I mean

Answer (score 1):

By using a decorator it is possible to *control* the dependency of the common parameter.

```
def master(*funcs):
    def wrapper(common_arg):
        for f in funcs:
            f(common_arg)
    return wrapper


def a(D1): print(f'-> a({D1})')
def b(D1): print(f'-> b({D1})')
def c(D1): print(f'-> c({D1})')


master(a, b, c)(common_arg='D1')
#-> a(D1)
#-> b(D1)
#-> c(D1)
master(a, c)(common_arg='D2')
#-> a(D2)
#-> c(D2)
```

Comment: I see, my mind was focused on the syntax sugar for decorators, lol, but also could just make this into one function that simply accepts a keyword argument at the end

Comment: No worries! Mmm but then it  could violate the requirement  "`Master(StoreInfo,GetAlternative)`" (also if my approach could be a bit on the limit)